# mapping one ecore to another ecore

Tags: eclipse, xsd, eclipse-emf-ecore

are there any open source tools to map one ecore model to another ecore model in graphical way ? I have two XSD's and corresponding ecore models for both of them; I would like to transform one ecore model to another ecore in a model driven way. Any open source tools that does this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EMF provides a standard Emf ecore mapping editor available in contextual menu of an ecore file (Map to Ecore... entry). I never used it but may be it can answer to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

EMF Epsilon can be used for model to model transformation. It isn't graphical, but textual though.